# TeleBot python Как определить тип сообщения пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Не могу сообразить как достать тип сообщения, отправленное пользователем, а именно как определить что пользователь отправил именно фото.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text', 'photo'])
def main(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        username = message.from_user.username

        if message.text == 'txt1':
            #some code..
        elif message.text == 'txt2':
            #code...
        elif     : #и вот тут нужно определить, что тип контента сообщения - фото
```

Comment: `print(message.content_type)` вам в помощь

Answer (score 2):

Через `content_types=['']`, в вашем случае:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
```

[Подробнее](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/#message-handlers)

Comment: То есть, для main функции нежелательно устанавливать `content_types = ['text', 'photo']` одновременно? Ибо эта функция по задумке должна принимать два типа сообщений - текстовых и фото

Comment: @Ian Faint если вам нужна особая обработка конкретно для фотографии, то легче сделать так. одновременно их тоже можно устанавливать, но с вашим запросом было бы легче разделить обработку текста и фото

Comment: в конце кода я прописал `bot.polling(none_stop = True)`, что бы бот не завершал свою работу. Внутри функции `main` я завожу локальный булеан `is_active`, который меняю в первых двух проверках кода, что выше (txt1, txt2). Эта переменная мне нужна одновременно для обработчика текстовых и фото сообщений, соответственно, если я разделю обработку текста и фото на два разных метода, то мне нужно делать `is_active` глобальным. А проблема в том, что из-за `bot.polling(none_stop = True)`, глобальный булеан `is_active` всегда будет принимать своё первоначальное значение, как бы я его ни менял

Answer (score 0):

думаю так должно сработать

```
try:
        photo_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'получил фото')
except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'получил что угодно, но определенно не фото')
```